# Can't configure Powershell New-AzureRmNotificationHub need input file?

Tags: powershell, azure, azure-powershell, azure-notificationhub

https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/powershell/resourcemanager/azurerm.notificationhubs/v2.7.0/new-azurermnotificationhub

To create new notification hub a JSON input file is needed as suggested in the link I provided, I can't find an example anywhere. Only need it just to be deployed.

Answer (score 0):

```
Hi Callum,

The JSON file can be in the following format. Below is the example for WNS and APNS Credential

Hub with WNS Credential

{
  "Location": "South Central US",
  "Tags": {
    "abc": "efg"
  },
  "Properties": {
    "WnsCredential": {
      "Properties": {
        "PackageSid": "ms-app://s-1-15-2-1817505189-427745171-3213743798-2985869298-800724128-1004923984-4143860699",
        "SecretKey": "w7TBprR-9tJxn9mUOdK4PPHLCAzSYFhp",
        "WindowsLiveEndpoint": "http://pushtestservice.cloudapp.net/LiveID/accesstoken.srf"
      }
    }
  }
}

Hub with APNS Credential
{
  "Location": "South Central US",
  "Tags": {
    "abc": "efg"
  },
  "Properties": {
    "ApnsCredential": {
      "Properties": {
        "KeyId": "XXX",
        "Token": "XXX",
        "AppName": "Sample",
        "AppId": "XXX",
        "Endpoint":"localhost"
      }
    }
  }
}
```